# set multiple value with comma in single variable select data from table

Tags: select, sql-server-2008-r2

set multiple value with comma in single variable select data from table

DECLARE @Values varchar(1000)

SET @Values = 'A, B, C'

SELECT
  blah
FROM 
  foo

blah value like A, B, C, D, E..

Comment: So, what's your question? Please spend some time to form your question in a crisp and clear form. If you can't spend time for your own issue then no one will.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @Crossing1_Table TABLE (Crossing_No NVARCHAR(200), userid INT, GameName varchar(50), 
    GameDate date, CrossingQty INT, ccount int) 
    DECLARE @Id int
    DECLARE @cross1 varchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @ganame varchar(50)
    DECLARE @gdate date
    DECLARE @Cqty int

```
DECLARE cur_emp CURSOR
STATIC FOR 
SELECT CrossingValue1, UserId, GameName, TodayDate, CrossingQty
FROM Game where GameListId=@Gamename and Cast(TodayDate as DATE)=@Gamedate

OPEN cur_emp
IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0
 BEGIN 
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_emp INTO @cross1, @Id, @ganame, @gdate, @Cqty
 WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
 BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Crossing1_Table
    SELECT CAST(Item AS INT), @Id, @ganame, @gdate, @Cqty, 1
    FROM dbo.SplitString(@cross1, ',')

 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_emp INTO @cross1, @Id, @ganame, @gdate, @Cqty

 END
END
CLOSE cur_emp
DEALLOCATE cur_emp
```